# kivy ScrollView не отображает список из Accordion

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, accordion

Хочу добавить на второй экран  в ScrollView "Accordion",но с превышение размеров экрана  превращается в пример на картинке.Может кто то знает как сделать прокручивающийся акардеон в скролвью?

[image: фото программы]

код py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Window.size = (300, 500
class VolAutoBus(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def changeScreen(self, next_screen):
        if next_screen == 'В Волосово':
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = 'SecondScreen'
        elif next_screen == 'Назад':
            self.ids.kivy_screen_manager.current = 'StartScreen'
class VolAutoBusApp(MDApp):
   def build(self):
        return VolAutoBus()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    VolAutoBusApp().run()
```

код kv file

```
<VolAutoBus>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'VolosovoAutoBus'
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
    ScreenManager:
        id: kivy_screen_manager
        StartScreen:
            name:'StartScreen'
        SecondScreen:
            id: SecondScreen
            name: 'SecondScreen'
<StartScreen@Screen>:
     тут код стартскрина
<SecondScreen@Screen>:
    id: layout_content
    ScrollView:
        Accordion:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            AccordionItem:
                title: '1111'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel1 text'
                    font_size:12
            AccordionItem:
                title: '2222'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel2 text'
                    font_size:32
                    color: (0,1.0,1)
            AccordionItem:
                title: '3333'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel3 text'
                    font_size:32
            AccordionItem:
                title: '4444'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel1 text'
                    font_size:12
            AccordionItem:
                title: '55555'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel2 text'
                    font_size:32
                    color: (0,1.0,1)
            AccordionItem:
                title: '66666'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel3 text'
                    font_size:32
            AccordionItem:
                title: '7777'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel1 text'
                    font_size:12
            AccordionItem:
                title: '88888'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel2 text'
                    font_size:32
                    color: (0,1.0,1)
            AccordionItem:
                title: '99999'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel3 text'
                    font_size:32
            AccordionItem:
                title: '100000'
                Label:
                    text: 'Panel1 text'
                    font_size:12
```